# How can I copy pictures I posted in other groups to my own album

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-photos

I belong to several photography groups.  I've posted pix to various ones.  Rather than re-upload them, is there a way to collect them all into an album on my profile?

Comment: Try to tag yourself in those pictures. Once you tagged, it will show in the section Photos you are tagged.